# calling PHP from shell fires repeatedly

Tags: php, shell

I'm having a problem on a VPS running CPANEL/WHM where calling a PHP script via `shell_exec()` causes it to reload the target repeatedly until the server crashes. I've removed the possibility that its something in the target script by creating a very simple example that shows the behavior, involving two scripts:

#### script to call from the web

```
# script: test.php
echo shell_exec('php target.php');
```

#### target script

```
 # script: target.php
 echo "Its a small world after all \n";
```

Running `test.php` from the command line produces the output you'd expect ("Its a small world after all") but calling test.php via a web browser is attempting to start `target.php` repeatedly until the server crashes.

I should note this does not happen with a non-php target; for example `shell_exec('ls')` works exactly as expected.

This does not happen on my local vagrant box, or on a VPS on digital ocean. I'm only getting this result on a CPanel server (which is where it has to live, ultimately).

While there are probably work-arounds possible, the root cause needs to be addressed as there are a few cases where this type of pattern is helpful for the application.

### Attempted Fixes / Explorations (based on comments)

- Web browser is not reloading the page multiple times, based on network tab info in Chrome
- Not browser related: called via CURL in verbose mode. Single call, hangs until web server crashes

Comment: What does target.php do?

Comment: @frank - the entirely of target.php is above. It outputs "Its a small world after all"

Comment: Why are you trying to execute another script in the shell from php? You could just include the file and it will run.

Comment: use something like httpfox or firebug's net tab, see what your browser is doing. possibly your server issuing a redirect or meta refresh causing the page to be continually re-hit.

Comment: @MarcB great suggestion, but unfortunately not the case.

Comment: @chip-dean the real-case is much more complex. This is the simplest example that shows the buggy behavior

Comment: perhaps something like auto_prepend, causing the script with exec() to be auto-included when it fires up, causing an infinite include cycle.

Comment: What browser do you have? Safari by example will try to load the page on the background, try to load it by curl on the command line

Comment: How do you load "test.php" in CPanel?

Answer (score 0):

Probably CPanel is running with a custom php.ini configuration which is perhaps doing something funky with auto prepending or appending files. So when it loads `target.php` it automatically includes `test.php`, and gets caught in the infinite loop. Since the other environments aren't using that configuration, they don't have the same problem.

Run the command with `-n` so it doesn't include a php.ini configuration. i.e.

```
shell_exec('php -n target.php');
```